# Detecting four fingers gestures (Cocoa)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In Cocoa I developed app which is agent (runs only as icon on upper status bar).
It can display popover window which is basically subclass of `NSWindow` with `NSView` as it's content.
Into another `NSView` subclass (which represents icon on status bar) I'm adding

```
    self.settingsPopoverTransiencyMonitor = [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSLeftMouseDownMask|NSRightMouseDownMask handler:^(NSEvent *event) {
    [selfReference hideSettingsPopover];
}];
```

So when user clicks outside popover windows it hides.
I want to implement similar behaviour when user swipes with four fingers up/down (so when Exposé or Mission Control are being launch).

I tried with lot of mask that are available in `NSEvent.h` but none of them helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First enable touch events in your `NSView`:

`view.acceptsTouchEvents = YES`

In your `NSView` subclass, override the touch event methods declared in the [`NSResponder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/swipeWithEvent%3a) superclass. If you want to recognize a 4-finger swipe gesture, you probably want `-swipeWithEvent:`. Since this will fire for swipe events that have any number of fingers, you would want to filter it to 4-finger gestures only. The method `-[NSEvent touchesMatchingPhase:inView:]` will return an array of `NSTouch` objects, one for each finger (ie. the count of the array is equivalent to the number of fingers).

To summarize, the implementation would look something like this:

```
- (void)swipeWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event
{
    NSArray *touches = [event touchesMatchingPhase:NSTouchPhaseTouching inView:self];
    if (touches.count == 4) {
        // Handle event here
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of my NSView subclass responds to `swipeWithEvent`. I tried with setting `acceptsFirstResponder` and `becomeFirstResponder` but with no luck.
BTW, I'm using your class INPopover, and it is super cool :)

Comment: Are you sure the system isn't intercepting the swipe events? Check Trackpad preferences in System Prefs and make sure that nothing else is assigned to 4 finger swipe.

Comment: Yep, after all I figured it out that I need to turn off swipe events in preferences to intercepts it in my app.
My app runs as agent and have customised popup menu but I can't figure it out how to hide it when user launch mission control/exposé with swipe gesture. Do you have some idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: I would advise that you post a separate question for that since it's irrelevant to this issue. Don't forget to mark this answer as correct if you got it working :)